# Add/Remove form field depending on radio select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, field

I'm currently building a medical form, and I want to make it a little more dynamic. So, one of the first fields is a radio that indicates whether the patient is male or female, and I'd like that when you choose one of those, the fields that are related to the other genre dissapear.

I tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Sex').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "Male"){
                $('#FemaleRelatedField').remove();
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Where #Sex is a radio type field (Male/Female) and #FemaleRelatedField is any given field that we won't need to answer when dealing with a male patient.

But it doesn't seem to work at all.

Thanks in advance for all of your answers.

Comment: Try $(this) instead of (this)

Comment: Small typo on code, you forgot to declare this as jquery variable, switch it to $(this).val()

Comment: Several people had the same answer :) Just for a little more info in case you're new to jQuery, `$(this)` returns a jQuery object which responds to the `.val()` method. `this` without the `$()` returns a plain javascript object which has no `.val()` method. `$()` is equivalent to `jQuery()`. [See here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

You have miss a `$` in your code near `if((this).val()` and insert your code inside `$(document).ready()`

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Sex').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Male"){
            $('#FemaleRelatedField').remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Changed to $(this).val() and added the $(document).ready, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: rturn some error? try to see what is $(this)val() in this way before if: console.log($(this).val()); @OscarB92